# React component how to simplify this onClick function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is not really a React specific question, but I think it helps to know the context. In a component I'm generating some table rows. Each row needs an onClick function that passes an id to the components handleUnlink method.

I got it to work with the code below, but it's making my head spin a bit and I have a feeling that this could be done in a simpeler way. Am I right?

```
var fn = function(id){
  return function(){
    this.handleUnlink(id);
  }.bind(this);
}.bind(this); 

var linkedListHtml = this.state.linkedList.map( p => {
  return(
    <tr key={p.id}>
    <td>{p.name}</td>
    <td><mui.Icon icon='action-highlight-remove' onClick={fn(p.id)}/></td>
    </tr>);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) also does partial application of any additional arguments, so you should be able to do this instead:

```
onClick={this.handleUnlink.bind(this, p.id)}
```

---

**Bonus:** The `this` argument to `bind()` is redundant if you're using `React.createClass()` to create your component, as it auto-binds methods for you, so I usually end up writing a `partial` helper:

```
'use strict';
var slice = Array.prototype.slice
function partial(fn) {
  var partialArgs = slice.call(arguments, 1)
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(this, partialArgs.concat(slice.call(arguments)))
  }
}
module.exports = partial
```

...

```
var partial = require('./utils/partial')
// ...
onClick={partial(this.handleUnlink, p.id)}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's even better then I hoped for. \o/